# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).addEventHandler is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm coding an Electron sample app, and I want the console to log "Start clicked!" whenever I click the start timer button. Instead, I get the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).addEventHandler is not a function.

Here is my renderer.js code:

```
document.getElementById('start').addEventHandler('click', _ => {
  console.log('Start clicked!');
})
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="countdown.css" />
      <title>Cool Countdown</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>This is awesome!</h1>
      <button id="start">Start Timer</button>
      <script>
        require('./renderer.js');
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's `addEventListener` not `addEventHandler`. When in doubt...look at the documentation

Comment: @charlietfl Oh, that makes sense. Sorry. I am used to working in Java which has EventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It's addEventListener, answered by @charlietfl. I accidentally but handler, not listener.